# How to set a different theme for a screen?

Tags: dart, flutter

I created the [Friendly Chat app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/index.html) and want to add a new screen with a different theme but it doesn't work :-(

The whole app has a `Brightness.dark` theme:

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build MaterialApp");
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Friendly Chat',
      theme: kTheme,
      home: new ChatScreen(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        SettingsScreen.PATH: (BuildContext context) => new SettingsScreen()
      },
    );
  }
}

final ThemeData kTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
  primaryColor: Colors.indigoAccent[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
);
```

When the user clicks a button I push the settings screen:

```
Map results = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SettingsScreen.PATH);
```

In the settings screen I change the `AppBar`'s `backgroundColor` and `brightness` but the new/different `brightness` has no effect (changing the `backgroundColor` works)

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State createState() => new SettingsScreenState();
}

class SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Settings"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent[700],
          brightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I change the settings screen AppBar theme to a light one?

**EDIT**

At the end I want:

- all screens have a dark AppBar background color with white title and icons
- settings screen (only) has a light AppBar background color with dark title and icons

**Bonus points:** How to set a different theme for the whole screen and not only for the AppBar

Comment: Edited my post for your bonus point

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can override the current theme by wrapping the desired widget in a [`Theme`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget

Typically you'd have something similar to :

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final AppBar appBar;

  CustomAppBar(): appBar = new AppBar();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Theme(
      child: appBar,
      data: new ThemeData.dark()
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => appBar.preferredSize;
}
```

Had to make a custom class because `Scaffold` requires a `PreferredSizeWidget`.

**EDIT**

To answer your "Bonus Point", it's dead simple.

Instead of wrapping the `AppBar` in a `Theme`, wrap the `Scaffold` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, had to set **primarySwatch** for the color on `ExpansionTile` up arrow in a specific screen, but then lost other TextTheme styles when just setting the primarySwatch.

Here's how to bring the existing TextTheme styles back into the custom Theme declaration:

```
ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
  textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme,
)
```

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget scaffold = Scaffold(
      body: _screenWidget(),
    );

    scaffold = Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
      child: scaffold,
    );

    return scaffold;
 }
```

Thanks to [@Remi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48424909/2162226)